# Just got hired but have to move all of a sudden

Tags: new-job, quitting, relocation

I just got hired for a sales position at a chain massage parlor. However, due to circumstances outside of my control, I have to move to a different state in about 3 weeks. I did not know about this move when I interviewed for this job and I really wish I could keep it cause I’m actually kind of excited to start it. I haven’t started the job yet but am scheduled to start training in 2 days.

I’m torn as to when I should tell my new job about this. I need money for the move but I feel that it’s wrong to not tell them now. They’re going to waste time and resources to start training me and I won’t even be here in a month. My mother and husband both think I should keep it so I can make money and then just tell them in a couple weeks or so but I’m not sure.

Would it be unprofessional to work a few weeks before telling the company? Could it hurt my chances of getting a job in the future?

Comment: When you say 'chain massage parlor' does that mean there are some in other places too?  Any chance any in the area you are moving?

Comment: Even if not, do you want to burn  bridges with them? What if you wanted to apply to another branch in your new city?

Comment: Lindsay, I changed your question from "What should I do?" to be more [on-topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for our site. If you don't think my changes accurately answer your question, feel free to [edit] the question to better reflect what you want to know.

Answer (score 35):

Be honest with them.

Explain your situation. Make sure you tell them that you are sorry and that this was an unexpected move.

Maybe they'll let you work for a few weeks, maybe not.

Either way, you'll get to be an honest person and keep your dignity. You'll feel better for it.

Comment: +1 people react surprisingly well to honestly too.

Answer (score 6):

I agree you should be honest with them.

Depending on how long your training is the company would probably prefer you to be honest, rather than knowingly go through training etc and then resigning as they could find a replacement in the meantime.

Also worth checking your employment contract regarding notice periods as you may find once you’ve started actually working you may be required to give them adequate notice. It depends on the company but should he stated in your contract or employment terms.

Have you checked if the chain exists in your new state? If so is it worth checking if they have any vacancies and seeing if there’s anyway you could transfer? You could look into it but talk to them first.

Answer (score 2):

They have a contractual notice period and so do you. Your only obligation is to keep that, especially if you are moving out of state.

A company will not keep you on longer than is absolutely required and usually will not do anything that is not in its best interest. Neither should you. Any courtesies should be within your contractual parameters not above them.